# Should we have a limit on the amount of tags one can add to his or her post?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Today I asked a question that had 7 (possibly 8) relevant tags but when I was done adding the tags I got this error message:

[image]

I wouldn't be allowed to upload my post until I removed at least two tags so I got rid of the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) & [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tags and proceeded to upload my post.

I have a few questions on the matter:

- **Why** does this limit exist?
- Should we make exceptions for certain questions and allow them to add more tags?

Comment: Cross dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/why-is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tags

Comment: _"Should we make exceptions for certain questions..."_ - What do you mean by _certain_? What kind of questions are you thinking of?

Comment: "you had to get rid of css and html tags" why did you choose these in particular? _Is it possible_ that the core of your issue was not related to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask yourself which of your tags are unnecessary. 
One of the easiest ways to do this is to look at which tag implied by another and delete that tag.

In your case [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) implies [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as jQuery is a JavaScript library. So you should delete [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Adding [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is actually bad, because people searching for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) that have no interest in jQuery at all will get your post as a result. (and people interested in jQuery should of course use that tag and not something generic as JavaScript).

If the tag system used at [so] would have such an "implied-by-hierarchy" information, then the interface could actually suggest which redundant tags to remove. But since it doesn't have that information, you'll have to remove those tags yourself.

In your position I would have started with deleting [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) (implied by [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), arguably less clear as with jQuery/JavaScript) first.

Answer (score 5):

Each tag should be able to stand on its own, accurately representing the scope of your question in a unambiguous manner, so that it's shown to potential answerers. You should decide which tags to use by asking yourself this question:

## If I was allowed a single tag, which would be the ones that will give my question more probability of being seen by someone that will be able to answer my question?

Tags like vertical-aligment and window-resize doesn't tell anyone in an unambiguous and concrete manner what kind of knowledge you would need to answer the question. You should prefer tags that reference knowledge the answerer *needs to have* to be able to understand the issue and answer the question.

Most of the time, it's not the amount of tags that will rise the probability of your question being answered, but that the tags selected will put your question in front of the people that are able to answer it. More tags will make it more likable that you select that tag, but it doesn't guarantee that any of those tags are the most effective ones or effective at all.